# jQuery and Link Anchor

Tags: jquery, css, anchor

Hello This is a particular question, and I do not know if jQuery can help me, or if even CSS would be enough in this case.

I have a link from a page that goes to another page, pointing to a link anchor:

```
<a title="Creazione Siti E-Commerce" href="http://mysite.com/it/servizi/#ecommerce">
```

goes to the anchor link in the page /it/servizi/

Everything is fine here.

What I want to achieve is:

The new page will scroll to the anchor using the jQuery scroll animation. So I should be able to tell to the jQuery code that when in the URL it finds an anchor like http://mysite.com/it/servizi/#ecommerce it will animate the scrolling.

Second point is that when it finds this kind of URL http://mysite.com/it/servizi/#ecommerce, the jQuery code will add a new class to a specific element in the page. ( I need it to change the color of the text, to help the user to see what has been selected, in this case #ecommerce)

It's difficult to explain. I hope someone will understand my point :(

Thanks.

Comment: There are plugins for this but I was never able to get it to work consistently cross-browser.  The page would jump to the anchor before the JavaScript could take over with a scroll.  It would jump to the link, jump back to the top, and then scroll down.  IE was most troublesome.

Comment: I'd suggest a terribly ugly trick which would be to create a link such as www.fru.com/mypage.html#prefix_targetanchor and the anchor in the page would be name "targetanchor". Then in JQuery, first you parse the url anchor and remove the prefix, and then you scroll to the resulting anchor name, which is the real one. Quick and really dirty.

Comment: Tricky, but maybe not impossible.  You probably need to look at the URL opening up into a full screen iFrame, or posting to a proxy page that grabs the HTML from the destination page and then modifies it.

Answer (score 0):

ok , one you are going to load the page where you are attending to do the magic , meaning in the `$(document).ready(function(){});` block , select all the anchors using jquery like this `var anchors = $('a');` , and then iterate trough all the anchors , inspect them one by one , and check if some one of them is containing `$(anchor).attr('html') = 'you'r value'` , and when you'r going to find this anchor , apparently using an IF block , do the rest of you'r code.

Answer (score 0):

you'll likely have to use something other then #youranchor.  browsers scroll to this automatically, so you can't use jquery to scroll to it.

have a look at this plugin:
http://www.mathias-bank.de/2007/04/21/jquery-plugin-geturlparam-version-2/

it lets you get at url parameters.

so you could change your url to something like http://mysite.com/it/servizi/&anchor=ecommerce

then use `var anchor = $(document).getUrlParam(“anchor″);` to get the anchor you need to scroll to.

and then you can also do:

```
$("#" + anchor).addClass('yourHighlightClass');
```

hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You should add

```
$(function(){
    var hash = document.location.hash;
    document.location.hash = '#';

    var element = $('a[name="'+hash.slice(1)+'"]');
    if (element.length){
        var top = element.offset().top;
        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:top }, 2000);
        element.addClass('selected');
    }
});
```

and in css create a class named `selected` with the effect you want the highlighted text to have..

```
.selected{color:red;}
```

on the receiving page..

**Demo code at** http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/XH72A/
**Demo example at** http://fiddle.jshell.net/gaby/XH72A/show/light/#line-80